# What happens when copying a document that is being edited on Windows10?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

I found my backup and sync program (Icedrive) never completes on my windows 10 computer, and I fear it is due to it resetting the copying progress when the file is edited.

I'm not talking about appending to document but rather the follow scenario

```
0.Initial
original | 012345
copied   | 

1.Copied half-way
original | 012345
copied   | 012

2.Edited
original | 0a23c5
copied   | 012

3.What to do now?
3.1 Continue to copy but the file is corrupt 
original | 0a23c5
copied   | 0123c5

3.2 Restarting 
original | 0a23c5
copied   |
```

Comment: Unless the writing process has locked the file, preventing opening by another process, the reader will see the written data “at the time it reads”.

Comment: So the 3.1 path will occur?

Comment: I assume normally copying and editing a file must be done concurrently and not in parallel on Windows.

Comment: Could you provide references?

Comment: I suppose I read “can occur” as theoretical. This Icedrive program should acquire file locks and/or provide secondary validation. For file locking in Windows, ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea